# Why does the function not work properly when processing numbers?

Tags: python

so I'm trying to get the of a given number. The thing is, the code prints the wrong message and it also doesn't work with all numbers. Why is that?

This is the part to get the factors:

```
thefactors = []
            d = 2
            while d*d <= number:
                while (number % d) == 0:
                    factors.append(d) 
                    number //= d
                d += 1
                break

            if number > 1:
                factors.append(number)
                print('The factors of {} are:'.format(number), thefactors)
```

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: 9 doesn't meet this criteria (odd numbers) `while (num % d) == 0`

Comment: that "break" shouldn't be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I see is that you are both checking that the square of `d` is less than `n` (`d*d <= n` or `d**2 <= n`) AND that you reassign `n` when a factor is discovered (`n //= d`). This is not including the unnecessary `break` statement.

Here's what I did:

```py
>>> def factorization(n):
        factors = []
        d = 2
        while d <= n:
            if n % d == 0:
                factors.append(d)
                n //= d
                d = 2
            else:
                d += 1
        return factors

>>> factorization(104)
[2, 2, 2, 13]
>>> factorization(9)
[3, 3]
>>>
```

This method implicitly checks that `d**2` is less than or equal to `n`, since, to satisfy the `while` condition, `n // d` must be less than or equal to `d`, thus `d**2` must be less than or equal to `n`.

To print the prime factorization:

```py
>>> num = 104
>>> factors = factorization(num)
>>> print(f"The prime factors of {num} are {factors}")
The prime factors of 104 are [2, 2, 2, 13]
>>> print(f"The prime factors of {num} are {', '.join(factors)}")
The prime factors of 104 are 2, 2, 2, 13
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work. Do you know why it says 'The factors of 1 are:' instead of 'The factors of MY NUM are:' ? How can I change that?

Comment: @fayewaii Do you want to print a literal `”MY NUM”`? I will update my answer once I get a response.

Comment: No, I meant that I want it to print the num I input like if I input 100 it should say 'The factors of 100 are"

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

1. You modify your original number (`num`) and print the modified value.
2. You `break` before trying any other divisor than 2.
3. You only `print` the result if `num > 1`.

Here is a working implementation:

```
# Back up original number for future use:
original_number = num
factors = []
d = 2
while d*d <= num:
    while (num % d) == 0:
        factors.append(d)
        num //= d
    d += 1
    # There shouldn't be a break here

if num > 1:
    factors.append(num)
    
# Fixed the indentation of the following line so that
# it is always printed, and print original_number
# instead of num as the latter has been modified.
print('The factors of {} are:'.format(original_number), factors)
```